# Buddypress export Profile Fields

Tags: buddypress, export, profiles

I am looking for some help in building a sql to export specific data from the DB.

In BuddyPress, I have a profile field set up called *Newsletter*.
I need to export a list of user from the db who have ticked the *Yes* (subscribe to newsletter).

I have identified the tables/fields in use in my DB.

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_bp_xprofile_data` WHERE `field_id` = 8 AND `value` LIKE 'yes'
```

Where user_id is the Registered user iD
Where field_id 8 is my Newsletter value.

Now I need to link this with  wp_user on user_id but don't know how to use 1 SQL on both table (sorry not my stuff).

Second table is wp_user where the Value of User_id should be "linked" to ID.

will appreciate some expert help

thx

RESOLVED AS

`SELECT wp_users.ID , wp_users.user_email FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data ON wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id = wp_users.ID , WHERE wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =8 AND wp_bp_xprofile_data.value = 'yes'`

Field ID = 8 being the Field you want to get (in my example, newsletter)
wp_bp_xprofile_data.value = Yes, being the value of my checkbox (ie Yes)

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: This where I am stuck 
SELECT  `wp_users`.`ID` , `wp_users`.`user_email` 
FROM  `wp_users` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_bp_xprofile_data` ON `wp_bp_xprofile_data`.`user_id` = `wp_users`.`ID`,
WHERE  `wp_bp_xprofile_data`.`field_id` =8 AND  `wp_bp_xprofile_data`.`value` =  `yes`

Comment: In case somebody need it, resolved it SELECT  wp_users.ID ,  wp_users.user_email 
FROM  wp_users 
LEFT JOIN  wp_bp_xprofile_data ON  wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id =  wp_users.ID , 
WHERE  wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id =8
AND  wp_bp_xprofile_data.value =  'yes'

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer and not a comment. This will help others and stay true to the QA protocols.

Answer (score 6):

Since the asker really doesn’t want to post the answer … someone has to do it:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID , wp_users.user_email 
FROM wp_users 
    LEFT JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data ON wp_bp_xprofile_data.user_id = wp_users.ID, 
    WHERE wp_bp_xprofile_data.field_id = 8 
    AND wp_bp_xprofile_data.value = 'yes'
```

`field_id = 8` being the Field you want to get (in my example, newsletter) `wp_bp_xprofile_data.value = 'yes'`, being the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Cheap rep. +1 ;)